# Fetching timestamp from firestore Cloud Functions nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am an interface where I have declared lastLogin as Date.

LastLogin looks like this: [image]

```
export interface User {
 lastLogin: Date,
}
```

I am fetching this timestamp in my cloud function and I want it as a timestamp so that I can subtract it from the current Timestamp.

```
const mentor: User = mentorDoc.data() as User;
const login = mentor['lastLogin'];
const lastOpen  =  mentor['lastLogin'].valueOf();
const currentTime  = new Date().getTime();
const diffMs = (currentTime - lastOpen); 
const diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
```

Last open shows like this :

```
063740174400.000000000
```

And when I use to like this :

```
const lastOpen  = new Date (mentor['lastLogin'].valueOf());
```

Output:

`undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change Date to firestore Timestamp both in the interface declaration as well as the collection field that holds the date in the firestore console

```
export interface User {
  lastLogin: firebase.firestore.Timestamp,
}
```

You can now retrieve the date and also update it, this time simply by passing a new Date object.

```
// Read currently saved Timestamp
const ref = db.collection<User>('users').doc(`${uid}`).get().toPromise()
const saved_date = ref?.data().lastLogin
const current_date = new Date()

// if you just want the Date difference in ms after retrieving the timestamp from firestore.
const diff = current_date.getMilliseconds() - (saved_date.toDate()).getMilliseconds() // Timestamp -> Date (ms)

// Update Timestamp using a Javascript Date object
 db.collection('..').doc('..').set({ lastLogin: current_date }, {merge:true}) 

// set creates the field while update works only if field already exists
```

Comment: I just want to subtract the date from firestore from the current date and print the difference in hours. How can I do that? I do not want to update any thing in firestore

Comment: edited, i have tried this and it works so work around this a bit please and upvote. I tried to be as specific as i could

Comment: You are declaring current_date as date whereas lastLogin is a timestamp

Comment: sorry use saved_date.toDate() see docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate to convert firestore timestamp to Javascript Date. Now both dates ae Javascript dates

Comment: Does not work. Says ```The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.```

Comment: use the getMilliseconds()  function on the Date property please to get a number. Im currently not a computer sorry

Comment: lastLogin is coming as 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224466/discussion-between-ajay131-and-christos-sirmakezis).